# Why does my grub screen (Advanced option) list 5.11.0-22-generic first, but the header files (?) is not present

Tags: grub2, kernel, vmware

I run vmware 16 player on ubuntu 20.04. When trying to start a vm I was informed that the header file(s) for 5.11.0-22-generic could not be found. (So the startup could not continue.)

When trying to download the missing file (via update, upgrade . . .), I realized I had no wired internet connection. In fact, there was no trace of one, so there is nothing to start/restart. (I tried several approaches to starting the network manager.)

In order to boot into a OS with internet, I chose the second kernel on the grub screen (5.8 . . . ), instead of the first (5.11.0-22). So I am able to submit this question:

Perhaps a download/update was interrupted?

How do I finish getting 5.11.0-22-generic on my machine? (If that is the best path.)

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?  The current HWE kernel is still 5.8 for *focal* or 20.04 (5.11 is still in -proposed/testing) and testing issues belong on bug trackers.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: guiverc: Thank you. I use ubuntu. I have no idea how "5.11" showed up on my grub screen. Is there a way to get rid of it, and use the next option - 5.8.0-59? Is it a bug if it pops up on my grub page, and I have never agreed to help test code?

Comment: guiverc: Follow up: This issue does not seem to qualify as a bug, per the url to which your link took me. In addition, I could not figure out how to submit a relevant bug report; though there is a section dealing with linux kernel issues. And the llink to get help did not work for me (#ubuntu-bugs).

Comment: guiverc: Another follow up - though I can run 20.04 by using advanced options. I note that "Grub Customizer" is on my 20.04. Perhaps it came with 20.04, as I don't recall installing it. The question: Is it considered safe to use?

Comment: The 5.11 kernel is used by 21.04, but won't be used by 20.04 until it reaches 20.04.3 (which is still in *testing*) meaning you've likely not running what you say (eg. Pop OS use software Ubuntu still has in *testing*) or have polluted your sources . Grub Customizer is not found in the 'main' repository (it's a 'universe' package with lower security checks; https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=grub-customizer&searchon=names) thus doesn't come on Ubuntu media; again you're not using Ubuntu or have a *fake* system.  You're not describing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: guiverc: The only linux I have used for 12 yrs is ubuntu. I have been using 20.04 since I installed it in 09/20 - in addition to 18.04 and W10 installs on the computer. I don't know how 5.11 files got on my system, but I guarantee they are listed on my grub screen. It may have happened over the last couple of days, when I worked on a W10 vm in order to b/u and restore an iphone (iTunes). (Again, a mystery.) I don't play with computers, I write engineering software (fortran/c/c++); so I just want to get the offending files off. But thank you. I will try Grub Customizer.

Comment: Just to wrap up: I used grub-customizer to: 1) Remove the two entries for 5.11, and 2) Edit the file/script Ubuntu menuentry - replacing the two instances of 5.11.0-22 with 5.8.0-59. Ubuntu now boots into 5.8.0-59 by default, and I have internet. Alles goot. (for now)